# SAS count a sequence of equal numbers

Tags: sas

I wish to get last number in a sequence of equal numbers. For example, I have the following dataset:

> X
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 0

Given that sequence of numbers I need extract the last number of a sequence of "ones" until appear a 0. That is what I want:

> X Seq
>
> 1 1
>
> 1 2
>
> 1 **3**
>
> 0 1
>
> 0 2
>
> 0 3
>
> 1 1
>
> 1 **2**
>
> 0 1
>
> 1 1
>
> 1 2
>
> 1 **3**
>
> 0 1

I need create a new dataset with the numbers in bold, that is:

> Seq1
>
> 3
>
> 2
>
> 3

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more option - use the NOTSORTED BY group option.

```
Data want;
Set have;
 By x NOTSORTED;

 Retain count;

 If first.x then count=1;
 Else count+1;

 If last.x then output;

 Keep count;
 Run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a proc summary with notsorted option here:

```
data math;
input x;
datalines;
1
1
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
0
1
;
run;

proc summary data=math;
by x notsorted;
class x;
output Out=z;
run;

data z (drop=_type_ x);
set z (rename=(_FREQ_=COUNT));
where _type_=1 and x=1;/*if you are looking for other number then 1, replace it here*/
run;
proc print data=z noobs;
run;
```

result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create group variables using a lag and then keep the last observation of each group you have created:

```
data temp;
   input x $;
   datalines;
    1
    1
    1
    0
    0
    0
    1
    1
    0
    1
    1
    1
    0
    ;
run;

data temp2;
    set temp;
    retain flag;
    if lag(x) > x then flag = _n_;
    if x = 0 then delete;
run;

data temp3 (keep = seq1);
    set temp2;
    seq1 + 1;
    by flag;
    if first.flag then seq1 = 1;
    if last.flag then save = 1;
    if missing(save) then delete;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using only one data step with a retain statement.

```
data have;
  input x @@;
  output;
  datalines;
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
;

data want(keep = count);
  set have end = last;
  retain x_previous . count .;

  if x = 0 then do;
    if x_previous = 1 then do;
      output;
      count = 0;
    end;
  end;

  else if x = 1 then count + 1;

  if last = 1 and count > 0 then output;

  x_previous = x;
run;
```

### Results

```
count
-----
3
2
1
4
1
```